# Bitcoin price history data

Tags: bitcoin-core, exchange-rate, history, charts

I need to get the Bitcoin price historical from when it started till today to generate graph and I don't won't to use any third party api. How this big companies are getting this Data
From where are they acquiring this data. How can i also get that without using this company api.
Any help will be appreciated !!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use a third party API. A price is just what an exchange or multiple exchanges see in real time when supply (sellers) and demand (buyers) meet at a certain price. So there is no authoritative neutral source of what the market price is at any point in time. Therefore I think you have to choose between an API provided by an exchange or a market observer (Bloomberg, CoinDesk etc).